# no suitable method found to override (CS0115)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to implement Drawer layout In Xamarin Studio, and on method overring of OnOptionItemSelect I am facing this issue

> 'DrawerLayoutExampe.MainActivity.OnOptionItemSelected(Android.Views.IMenuItem)': no suitable method found to override (CS0115)

Comment: Please show some code. What does your class look like and the method you're trying to overload?

Comment: Thanks Gerald, my issue resolve, Actually the problem is namespace and class name are same, so it gives us error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of this is my namespace name and class name is same so it gives me error, I refactor my namespace so bug resolve